# no match for 'operator =' for 3d vector

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

I am trying to convert a vector of coordinates std::vector surface into a 3D array, setting all entries of the 3d array that are contained in surface to 0;
however I am getting a no match for operator array.
I looked up the error several times but did not find my case....

`std::vector<coordinates>` surface is global.
the coordiantes simply look like

```
struct coords{
    int xvalue;
    int yvalue;
    int zvalue;

    coords(int x1, int y1, int z1) : xvalue(x1),yvalue(y1),zvalue(z1){}
    ~coords(){}
};
typedef struct coords coordinates;
```

and my method is:

(doubleBox is a typedef for a 3D double vector)

```
doubleBox levelset::putIntoBox( vector<coordinates> surface){
    int xMaxs, yMaxs,zMaxs;
    for (vector<coordinates>::iterator it = surface.begin() ; it != surface.end(); ++it){
        if (it->xvalue > xMaxs)
            xMaxs = it->xvalue;
        if (it->yvalue > yMaxs)
            yMaxs = it->yvalue;
        if (it->zvalue > zMaxs)
            zMaxs = it->zvalue;
        //check invalid surface
        if (it->xvalue < 0 || it->yvalue <0 || it->zvalue<0)
            cout << "invalid surface with point coordinates below 0 !" << endl;
    }
    doubleBox surfaceBox[xMaxs+1][yMaxs+1][zMaxs+1];

    int max = std::ceil(sqrt(xMaxs*xMaxs + yMaxs*yMaxs + zMaxs*zMaxs));
    std::fill(&surfaceBox[0][0][0],&surfaceBox[0][0][0] + sizeof(surfaceBox)*sizeof(surfaceBox[0])/ sizeof(surfaceBox[0][0]) / sizeof(surfaceBox[0][0]), max);

    for (vector<coordinates>::iterator it = surface.begin() ; it != surface.end(); it++){
        surfaceBox[it->xvalue][it->yvalue][it->zvalue] = 0.0;
    }

    return surfaceBox;
}
```

the output is (declaring that the error lies in the second for-loop)

```
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\vector.tcc:160:5: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::vector<std::vector<double> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<std::vector<double> > >]
     vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\vector.tcc:160:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const int' to 'const std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double> > >&'
..\src\Levelset.cpp: In member function 'doubleBox levelset::putIntoBox(std::vector<coords>)':
..\src\Levelset.cpp:295:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Maybe this problem is caused by the fact that std::fill is used inappropriately??

Comment: please provide doubleBox definition.

Comment: typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double> > > doubleBox;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `doubleBox` is defined as `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>`, why do you define  `doubleBox surfaceBox[xMaxs+1][yMaxs+1][zMaxs+1];` in this way?

What you defined is a 3 dimensional array whose element type is `doubleBox`, which means that every element is of type `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>`, which is not what you want.

You may need something like `doubleBox surfaceBox(xMaxs + 1, std::vector<std::vector<double>>(yMaxs + 1, std::vector<double>(zMaxs + 1)));`

Comment: thanks! so what would doubleBox surfaceBox(xMaxs + 1, yMaxs + 1, zMaxs + 1) be doing? I though intializing would be more straight forward...

Comment: @Rea Do not consider doubleBox as a 3 dimensional array. It's a vector of vector of vector. doubleBox surfaceBox(xMaxs + 1, yMaxs + 1, zMaxs + 1)  is not a syntax correct way to construct it.

Comment: ok, I always thought because I can access each entry like an array it is also constructed like this ....  like when I use surfacebox[i][j][k] in a for loop

Comment: Can I also automatically fill each entry with the same value during construction? like  'doubleBox surfaceBox(xMaxs + 1, std::vector<std::vector<double>>(yMaxs + 1, std::vector<double>(zMaxs + 1, doublevalue)));'

Comment: @Rea Yes, you can do it this way.